# How to apply filter in sum function in java stream

Tags: java

I'm trying to apply a filter in the sum function.

```
Integer lyf = events.stream().mapToInteger(i -> i).filter(sum()>100?100:sum());
```

but I'm facing an error.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want to do. Like do you want to condition on the sum of the integer or do you want to filter the stream of integers and then sum the valid ones? You also might want to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What do you want to do in `.filter(sum()>100?100:sum());` ?

Comment: @lczapski , what you wrote won't execute.

Comment: You can also look into using `Math.min`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first calculate the sum,

```
int sum = events.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
lyf = sum>100 ? 100 : sum;
```

Update:
If you want to short circuit the Stream pipeline once a partial sum > 100 is reached, you can use a filter as below,

```
AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);
events.stream()
        .mapToInt(sum::addAndGet)
        .filter(i -> sum.get() > 100)
        .mapToObj(i1 -> {
            if (sum.get() < 100)
                return sum.get();
            else
                sum.set(100);
            return sum;
        })
        .findAny();
System.out.println(sum.get());
```

Comment: That answers the OP question.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to short circuit the Stream pipeline once a partial sum > 100 is reached. That would be desirable if the Stream is very large and a small prefix of it already has a sum > 100. You wouldn't want to process the entire Stream in such case.

Comment: @Eran I have updated the answer to handle short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use one of the `short-circuiting` functions of the Stream. In this case I would use the `allMatch()` function.

Here's a small test I wrote to verify

```java
@Test
public void testShortCircuitingSum() {
   final AtomicInteger totalSum = new AtomicInteger(0);
   IntStream.range(0, 1000).allMatch(value -> totalSumLessThan100(totalSum, value));
   System.out.println("Final sum is " + totalSum.get());
}

private static boolean totalSumLessThan100(AtomicInteger totalSum, int value) {
   if (totalSum.addAndGet(value) <= 100) {
      return true;
   }
   System.out.println("Total sum is " + totalSum.get() + ". Short-Circuiting at value " + value);
   System.out.println("Setting the value to 100");
   totalSum.set(100);
   return false;
}
```

Which prints

```
Total sum is 105. Short-Circuiting at value 14
Setting the value to 100
Final sum is 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do filtering and adding in steam with `reduce`:

```
Integer lyf = events.stream().reduce(0, (acc, v) -> acc > 100 ? 100 : (acc + v));
```

Other approach with `short circuit` to stop when sum > 100 is reached:

```
AtomicInteger acc = new AtomicInteger(0);
events.stream()
    .allMatch(x ->
        acc.updateAndGet((a) -> Math.min(100, (a + x) )) < 100
    );
Integer lyf = acc.get();
```